# js-blitz выводит ошибку, не могу понять в чем причина

Tags: javascript

## Поиск чисел в массиве с определённой суммой

Дан массив целых чисел и целое число k. Нужно определить, есть ли в массиве два числа, сумма которых равна k .

Пример:

Вход: nums = [10, 15, 3, 7], k = 17
Выход: true
Примечания
В качестве решения предоставьте функцию следующего вида:

```
/** @returns Boolean */  
module.exports = function(nums, k) {  
   // ваш код здесь  
}
```

Мое решение:

```js
module.exports = function(nums, k) {
    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++) {
        for (let j = 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
            if (nums[i] + nums[j] == k) {
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Так в чем ошибка то?

Comment: выполнение функции закончится после первой итерации вложенного цикла

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Вывод постпроцессора
stdout:
1.50
stderr:

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko stdout:
echo "make::build"
make::build
stderr:

Comment: Непонятная ошибка. Добавьте информацию об ошибке в вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Ты забыл тот случай, когда в массиве один элемент, а коэффициент равен этому элементу, умноженному на два, а также тот случай, когда то же самое, но много элементов.

```
for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
      if (nums[i] + nums[j] == k && i !== j) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  };
  return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = function(nums, k) {

        var temp = [];
        var len = nums.length;
        for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
            if(temp[nums[i]] == k - nums[i]){ 
                console.log(nums[i], k - nums[i])
                return true;
            }
            else{
                temp[k - nums[i]] = nums[i];
            }
        }
        return false;

}
```

Вероятно, ошибка возникла еще и из-за ограничения по времени. Это линейное решение данной задачи.